# whl file installation using command prompt

Tags: python, pip, pocketsphinx, python-wheel

I'm using IDLE(3.6.0) 32 bit and I've tried installing some packages using

```
pip install pocketsphinx-0.1.3-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
```

but i keep on getting an error saying:

> pocketsphinx-0.1.3-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Am I installing the right file?

Answer (score 0):

You're using Python 3.6.0 and trying to install a wheel for Python 3.5. Synchronise versions — either use Python 3.5 or download a wheel for Python 3.6.